# Create array of differences in col between two adjacent numbers in an array python/pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pyspark, difference

I have a column of arrays made of numbers, ie `[0,80,160,220]`, and would like to create a column of arrays of the differences between adjacent terms, ie `[80,80,60]`

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this in Python or PySpark? I'm thinking of something iterative (ith term minus i-1th term starting at second term) but am really stuck how to code that. Thanks!

Comment: `[arr[i] - arr[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(arr))]`

Comment: Does the below answer answer's your question? Or do you have any doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
d=[0,80,160,220]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns= ['col_list'])
df['col_new']=df['col_list'].diff()
print(df)
#output
   col_list  col_new
0   0        NaN
1   80       80.0
2   160      80.0
3   220      60.0
```

Also, if you want to delete the row with `NaN` you can do:

```
df.dropna(subset = ['col_new'])

#output

   col_list  col_new
1   80       80.0
2   160      80.0
3   220      60.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a 'TypeError: 'int' object is not interable' when trying this, but the first solution that uses range works

Comment: But I initially forgot to say that I want to create a column of list_differences based on another col containing the arrays in a dataframe. Sorry I wasn't specific enough initially. I've tried to scale up the working solution [arr[i] - arr[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(arr))] to:
 df=df.withColumn('col_new', [F.col('col_list'[i]) - F.col('col_list'[i - 1]) for i in range(1, F.size(col('col_list')))]) but this produces TypeError: 'column' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. When I change the range to range(1,2)  to simplify, it produces: AssertionError: col should be column'. Any ideas?